# How to make the width of the DIV depends on its content and then align center?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the width of the parent div depends on how many inline-block displayed boxes can fit in one row. But with the width of the parent div reaches 100% and the width of the other box is too wide to fit on the first row it goes down. It's okay but the width of the parent too should shorten a bit and align it horizontally center so no undesired spaces can be seen. Here the codepen. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aXJLQN

if the width of the boxes is below 200 it works just fine but when ! increase the width to 200 there are unnecessary spaces to the right.

HTML:

```
<div class="hello">
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hello{
   background: red;
   display: table;
   width: auto;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.hi{
   display: inline-flex;
   width:200px;
   height:170px;
   margin: 10px;
   background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the property `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`?

Comment: not yet. will try

Comment: Ok, but change the `display` property of `.hello` to `block` too for it to work.

Comment: not working. The boxes disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have provided parent `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;`
This will help you.

```css
.hello{
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.hi{
  display: inline-flex;
  width:200px;
  height:170px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">
  <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
   <div class="hi"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Anytime !! It would be helpful if you accept the answer. Thanks !

Comment: Yeah I will. but It won't allow me. i stlla have to wait for 6 minutes after the answer has been posted

Comment: and Ey, can we do it without centering the boxes. ?

Comment: You mean the last box shouldn't be centered??

Comment: yes. I will use it on a movie list and it will be weird if it's in the center.

Comment: try `justify-content: space-between;` maybe this is what you are looking for. Maybe you could add a image of whats coming right now and what you want

Comment: Try to change the width of the boxes to 150. the red div perfectly fit the entire thing without unnecessary spaces. and it's aligned in the center

Comment: i want to keep the 10px margin so I dont need the justify-content.